# CSS Classes in ASP.NET Core project suddenly not recognized

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So I re-opened a project I was working on today, started without debugging, and what I saw in the browser was a mess. After checking out the code I noticed that classes like img-responsive, carousel are not recognized any more and all the design I made is a mess right now. What should I do? I did not changed anything since the last time I ran the project and back then everything was fine.

Here is whats in _Layout.cshtml

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</environment>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the css file is available for your browser to download?

Comment: Yes, I also added my _Layout.csthml in the original post.

Comment: The `~` prefix is used by asp.net only in their element types. Remove this from any elements that are pure HTML elements like `link`, `script`, etc.

Comment: Check the browsers downloaded files, are the external css files there? You should be able to navigate to them and view them in that browser's session. Use the browsers development tools.

Comment: Removing ~ didn't change anything. I really don't understand what is going on since I literally changed nothing since I last ran the project.

Comment: is googleapis & ajax.aspnetcdn.com are accessible?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the difference in the environment variable that is set when you run your application in debug and release mode. Your markup makes use of environment tag helper to `include` or `exclude` the markup used to reference the location of your css file. Have you checked whether your browser is able to download the css files referenced in your html?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I meddled with the Bootstrap version. I managed to re-create what happened in a different project by using Bootstrap 4 instead of 3.x and that seems to have caused the changes.